# Is it possible to use SSL when SendGrid retrieves a CSV file from my server?

Tags: sendgrid

I would like to use SendGrid's feature where I create a recipient list by supplying a URL to a CSV file.  In my case, the CSV file is dynamically created using arguments in the URL, which essentially acts as query parameters.  The issue is that this leaves a wide-open security hole, whereby anyone who knows this URL can access data from the server.  To deal with that, I would like to use a secret `key` parameter in the URL to restrict access.  But unless SSL is used in the request, this `key` value will be sent in plain-text, defeating its purpose.

Is there a way to use SSL in the request?  Alternatively, if there's another method of restricting access only to SendGrid's servers, I'm listening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have SendGrid retrieve a file using SSL, simply provide a URL that has `https` as the protocol (e.g. `https://myserver.com/file-server?list=awesome&key=secretpassword123`)

Comment: Ah yes, I had tried that, but at first I got "invalid file" when checking.  It turned out to be an SSL problem on my end, but that's the only error SendGrid gives, so it was impossible to figure out.  You should provided more detailed error reporting.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I will certainly pass it on!